# Парсинг html-таблицы из разметки

Tags: c#, алгоритм, парсер, грамматика

Доброго времени суток всем! Есть такая задача. Имеется некий синтаксис разметки, определяющий таблицы. Синтаксис очень простой, он использует два символа (символ # для определения заголовочных ячеек таблицы и символ | для ограничения обычных ячеек) и символ перевода строки (показывающий окончание строки таблицы). Покажу на примере:

```
# заголовок1  # заголовок2  # заголовок 3 #
| ячейка1 стр1| ячейка2 стр1| ячейка3 стр1|
| ячейка1 стр2| ячейка2 стр2| ячейка3 стр2|
```

Эту нехитрую конструкцию надо распарсить в такую html-размекту:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>заголовок1</th>
        <th>заголовок2</th>
        <th>заголовок3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ячейка1 стр1</td>
        <td>ячейка3 стр1</td>
        <td>ячейка4 стр1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ячейка1 стр2</td>
        <td>ячейка3 стр2</td>
        <td>ячейка4 стр2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Я не силен в подобных вещах, поэтому хотел бы спросить у знающих людей, как это можно сделать и куда вообще копать? К сожалению использование сторонних библиотек невозможно (таковы условия задачи). Какие тут вообще могут быть  применены алгоритмы и средства? Также хотел бы уточнить, что сами тексты с этиой разметкой могут быть довольно объемными, поэтому производительность тоже важна. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: что делать, если в значении ячейки будет символ `|`?

Comment: @Grundy в данный момент это несущественно. давайте представим, что таких ячеек вообще не будет или что у нас есть алгоритм, позволяющий такие символы экранировать

Answer (score 2):

В качестве альтернативного решения можно воспользоваться [заменой с помощью регулярного выражение](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149475(v=vs.110).aspx)

C# позволяет использовать [именованные группы](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#named_matched_subexpression)

Регулярное выражение может быть таким:

```
(?<startline>^)?((?<border>\|)?(?<header>#)?(?<cellvalue>[^#|]+))?(?<endline>[#|\r\n]+$)?
```

В качестве обработчика совпадений можно использовать следующую функцию:

```
m =>{
    var replaced = new StringBuilder();
    if (m.Index == 0) // если в самом начале строки - добавляем тег table
        replaced.AppendLine("<table>");

    if (m.Groups["startline"].Success) // если попалась новая строка - добавляем тег tr
        replaced.AppendLine("<tr>");

    if (m.Groups["border"].Success) // если нашли границу ячейки - вставляем значение обернутое в теги td
        replaced.AppendLine($"<td>{m.Groups["cellvalue"].Value.Trim()}</td>");
    else if (m.Groups["header"].Success) // если нашли границу ячейки заголовка - вставляем значение обернутое в th
        replaced.AppendLine($"<th>{m.Groups["cellvalue"].Value.Trim()}</th>");

    if (m.Groups["endline"].Success) // если дошли до конца строки - закрываем тег tr
        replaced.AppendLine("</tr>");
    if (m.Index == table.Length) // если дошли до самого конца - закрываем тег table
        replaced.AppendLine("</table>");

    return replaced.ToString(); // возвращаем результат
}
```

При запуске с флагом [RegexOptions.Multiline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) буде получен следующий результат:

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th>заголовок1</th>
<th>заголовок2</th>
<th>заголовок 3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ячейка1 стр1</td>
<td>ячейка2 стр1</td>
<td>ячейка3 стр1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ячейка1 стр2</td>
<td>ячейка2 стр2</td>
<td>ячейка3 стр2</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, как-то так будет быстрее всего:

```
string Convert(string str){
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<table>\n  <tr>\n");

    var header = false;
    for (int l = -1, i = 0; i < str.Length; i++){
        switch (str[i]){
            case '#':
            case '|':
                if (l > 0){
                    sb.Append(header ? "    <th>" : "    <td>");
                    sb.Append(str.Substring(l, i - l).Trim());
                    sb.Append(header ? "</th>\n" : "</td>\n");
                }
                l = i + 1;
                header = str[i] == '#';
                break;
            case '\n':
                l = -1;
                sb.Append("  </tr>\n  <tr>\n");
                break;
        }
    }

    sb.Append("  <tr>\n</table>");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Если нужно больше скорости, можно попробовать заранее рассчитывать `capacity` для `StringBuilder` (скажем, прикинув, какая в среднем длина у ячейки) и избавиться от `Trim()` (не уверен, что сильно поможет, но мало ли).

Кстати, если вдруг возникнет задача экранировать «|» и «#», можно добавить (и тогда уж заменить `.Trim()` на некий `ConvertValue()`, обрезающий лишнее и разъэкранирующий значение):

```
            case '\\':
                i++;
                break;
```